# Is it possible to deploy IIS based application into service fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have an ASP.NET MVC app, heavily uses System.Web, Is it possible to deploy in Service Fabric?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that by using containers. Here's a [blog post](https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/running-windows-containers-on-azure-service-fabric/) about how to do that. Create your cluster using Windows Server 2016 nodes, with the Containers feature enabled.

(e.g. in Azure, use the '2016-Datacenter-with-Containers' sku.)

Comment: Docs on using containers for applications that rely on IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview#scenarios-for-using-containers

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

If you just want your application to be hosted on SF, host it as a [Guest Executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app) but with this approach you will miss native SF Features.

You can also [Create MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend) native to SF Cluster with SDK provided.

Comment: Guest Executable wont work it needs a self hosted application(ex. exe), we are working to convert to asp.net core (.net framework) in the mean time wondering how to use the IIS Express.

Comment: you can make it as a guest executable with the use OWIN Self hosting. refer [this](http://www.erbrech.com/blog/2016/11/01/Hosting-a-web-application-in-Service-Fabric.html) for details on exactly what you want.